# When Does $\sigma(q^k)$ Have a Prime Factor Greater Than $q$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

> Let $q$ be prime and $k$ be a natural number. When does $\sigma(q^k)$ have a prime factor greater than $q$?

We can slightly reduce the problem by noting that
$$\sigma(q^k)=\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}$$
Thus if $p\nmid q-1$, then $p\mid \sigma(q^k)$ if and only if $p\mid q^{k+1}-1$. Clearly a prime $p>q$ does not divide $q-1$, so $\sigma(q^k)$ has a prime factor greater than $q$ if and only if $q^{k+1}-1$ does.
Using this restatement, if one takes a look at one of my answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343354/prove-that-there-exists-a-prime-p-such-that-p-mid-an-bn-and-p-n/2344119#2344119) question we see this is the case when $k+1\ge q$ letting $a=q$, $b=1$, and $n=k+1$ (note the question requires $b>1$, but the proof only uses [Zsigmondy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem) in which $b>0$ suffices). However clearly this is true in more than just this case. Can we describe all cases in which this is true, or at least expand the set of $(q,k)$ for which we know that this holds?
**Edit**
Lets define $\kappa(n)$ to be the smallest prime congruent to $1\mod n$. A modified argument of that in the linked question, where we restrict $b$ to $1$, leads one to conclude that there exists a prime $\ge \kappa(n)$ that divides $q^n-1$. Thus if
$$\kappa(k+1)\ge q$$
(or really $\kappa(k+1)\ge q-1$ since $q\nmid q^n-1$), then $\sigma(q^k)$ satisfies the problem, slightly increasing the set of valid $(q,k)$.

Comment: When $k+1$ is even, Because number of   terms of series representing sum of divisors is equal to $k+1$ and if it  is even then there is a common factor like $q+1$ in it; $\sigma=[q^k(q+1)+q^{k-1}(q+1)+ . . . +(q+1) ]$.

Comment: @sirous However, unless $q=2$, since $q$ is a prime $2\mid q+1$ and so any prime factors contributed by $q+1$ will be smaller than $q$.

Comment: the only even prime i.e. 2 always is disturbing. What I claim is for odd primes and is correct.

Comment: Wont you down vote me if I post this as an answer?

Comment: @sirous the thing is you found a factor but I’m looking for prime factors.

Comment: Oh I see, I must be more accurate. Then only prime 2 gives $2+1=3$ as a factor if $k+1$ is even.For other primes In most cases other factor is prime greater than q .

Comment: For example $3^4-1=16\times 5$, $3^5-1=242=2.11^2$,$5^4-1=8.71$, $5^5-1=4\times 11\times 71$. For large primes it is not known.